# Java SQLException on a string that runs in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

I am trying to make an inserction of a cliente.

When I print the string from the executeUpdate, copy and paste on mysql, the data is inserted with no problem.

The Exception has the follow description:

> Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update cliente set honorarioMensal = 2000.2 where cnpj = 'cnpj_ex'' at line 2

Can somebody help me?

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        try {
            Industria industria = IndustriaDB.getById(1);
            System.out.println(industria);
            Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario("Func1","Func1");
            funcionario.setCustoMensal(22);
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente("cnpj_ex", "nome_ex",industria);
            cliente.setPreco((float) 2000.2);
            System.out.println(cliente);
            System.out.println(cliente.getFuncionario());
            ClienteDB.inserir(cliente);
            ClienteDB.deletar(cliente);
        } catch (ContexataException ge) {
            System.out.println("---> " + ge.getMessage());
            System.out.println("---> Detalhamento do erro: ");
            ge.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }



}


public class ClienteDB extends Conexao{ 

    public static void inserir(Cliente cliente) throws ContexataException, SQLException, NullPointerException {
        Connection conn = Conexao.getConnection();
        try {
            String createString = 
                    "INSERT into cliente "
                    + "(cnpj, nome, id_Industria) " 
                    + "values('" +  cliente.getCnpj() + "','"
                    + cliente.getNome() + "',"
                    + cliente.getIndustria().getId() + ");";
            if (cliente.getFuncionario() != null){
                createString = createString + "\n update cliente set cpf_Funcionario = '" + cliente.getFuncionario().getCpf() + "' where cnpj = '" + cliente.getCnpj() + "';";
                }
            if (cliente.getPreco() != 0.0){
                createString = createString + "\n update cliente set honorarioMensal = " + cliente.getPreco() + " where cnpj = '" + cliente.getCnpj() + "';";
                } 
            System.out.println("SQL: " + createString);
            executeUpdate(conn, createString);
            System.out.println("Novo cliente inserido!\n");
      //  } catch (SQLException e) {
      //    throw new ContexataException("Erro ao inserir novo cliente.");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw new ContexataException("Alguns dados não foram preenchidos suficientemente para o banco de dados!");
        } finally {
            Conexao.closeAll(conn);
        }


    }

public class Cliente { // only the atributes are necessary...

    private String cnpj;
    private String nome;
    private float preco;
    private Industria industria;
    private Funcionario funcionario;
    // getter and setter...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `\n` characters in the query string. You shouldn't use them, check your code and remove invalid characters.

```
if (cliente.getFuncionario() != null){
createString = createString + " update cliente set cpf_Funcionario = '" +    cliente.getFuncionario().getCpf() + "' where cnpj = '" + cliente.getCnpj() + "';";
}
if (cliente.getPreco() != 0.0){
createString = createString + " update cliente set honorarioMensal = " + cliente.getPreco() + " where cnpj = '" + cliente.getCnpj() + "';";
}
```

And you can't write`update` in the `insert` statements.

Comment: Still didn't work.

My update are not in the insert statements, they are separated by ;
Why can't I do that?
In mysql I have no problem in doing that

Comment: Because you are using multiple statements in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot think about your problem like if you were typing the commands in a GUI. You must execute one executeUptade per statement rather than a batch of them. Of course also remove the ; at the end of the statement.

In fact GUIs probably will split your sql sentences and then send them one by one to SQL one by one.